# CSS how to make a normal font site for mobile screen

Tags: html, css

the mobile screen is 240 x 320, I've got a menu with 5 items, the font-size is 12pt, in the mobile screen I decrease the font-size and make it 1-2 pt, is too small to see, but if I make bigger than that then it not fit in the screen, how to solve this?

Comment: create a vertical menu instead of horizontal menu.

Comment: Did you already adapt this site for in-between resolutions like 320, 480, 768px?

Answer (score 0):

What program are you now using for your now using for your coding of html?

But I'd sugest to make the wordspacing, and menu blocks smaller in the width. With that you can save space, and see if you van make it 3-4p.
Otherwise, you just need to do trail and error.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should leave the standard font-size defined as 12pt and define the font-size for the mobile screen in em instead of pt. You could consider making a slide-in menu instead, so it's readable ( = more user friendly). In that way it won't disturb the site since you only have a single icon somewhere on the page that triggers the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice: use 'em' instead of 'pt' as the font-size unit.

The objective is that when you change the base font-size, all children elements will follow.